# String changes after passing by reference

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012

I am writing a simulation project in C++ using Visual Studio 2012 (standard C++ with no /clr support) and I face the following problem.
In the code somewhere I pass a string by reference:

```
theClassObject->Method("12345")
```

where the definition of the method in the class is:

```
TheClass::Method(const std::string& STR) {..}
```

and when I check the value of the STR during debugging it has four more bytes in front, for example "~#.a12345" and the length of the string is increased by these four bytes.
In other places of the code with other similar methods this does not happen.

Did I miss some compiler option for the project or there are other reasons I miss?

I am not sure if I provided all the information needed, but I could if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should not happen. From what you posted, it's pretty much impossible to guess what went wrong. Can you reduce your problem to a subset that is still compilable and post that?

Comment: You are sending it as const reference, so you cannot change the string inside the function Method() , It is being changed somewhere else. Can you post a sample working code?(SSCCE)

Comment: It is strange... you are altering a const reference! Post the implementation of `TheClass::Method(const std::string& STR)`. It is probably a debug configuration which is showing a wrong value.

Comment: Sounds like memory corruption, run the program through a memory checker (i.e. valgrind on linux).

Answer (score 2):

This quacks loudly like a module boundary problem, calling code in another DLL that was built with an incompatible version of std::string or incompatible compiler settings.  Like _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING.

The only fix for it is recompiling *everything* with the exact same compiler version, C++ library and build settings.

Exposing C++ objects across module boundaries is a perilous adventure.  Especially the ones in the std namespace and especially as of late with C++11 bringing big changes to the standard library implementation.  Truly trouble-free DLL interfaces requires pretty draconian measures, the kind that look a lot like COM.